# How do you split or seperate links in css eg. home, about us links

Tags: css, hyperlink, alignment, css-position

I would like to know how to split or sperate hyperlinks from eachother, i also would like to know how to align or position where the links go. ps. i am just beginning so this is probably basic.

thanks

Comment: "Split" what,  *how*?

Comment: First thing, you should learn css from basics and you can solve this issue by using margin in your anchor tag.

Comment: start trying horizontal padding

Comment: can u atleast try and share what u have acheived than getting ready made answers from here

Comment: Did understand a word about what you are trying to say.

Comment: by split i mean seperate the "home" and "about" links. so they are not stuck together.

Comment: html { 
      background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/Tom/Pictures/93af2cd5d83f6f839db98e6d5079b4f4.jpg);
 }
 
 h1 { 
  color: gray;
  }
  
  a:visited {
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}


a:active {
    color: yellow;
 }
 

a { 
background-color:gray; filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:0.4; 
}

Comment: this is what i have in my "styles.css" tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your problem. But from the code you given i just added some changes. Try this.

```
 html { background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/Tom/Pictures/93af2cd5d83f6f839db98e6d5079b4f4.jpg); } 
 h1 { color: gray; } 
 a:visited { color: black; } 
 a:hover { color: yellow; } 
 a:active { color: yellow; } 
 a { background-color:gray; filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:0.4; padding:0px 15px; }
```

Comment: thank you that helped alot! now i just need to wait on aligning or positioning

Comment: <!doctype html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<h1>Home</h1>

<a href="home.html"> Home </a>

<a href="myproducts.html"> My Products </a>

<a href="about.html"> About </a>

Comment: this is what i have i know it is basic

Comment: so what kind of alignment and positioning you want?

Comment: just in the center of my page

Comment: you mean the home tile and menu links should come center of the page?

Comment: yes like the about, home, my products they are all links

Comment: if you like my answer, select it as a answer using tick mark.